# [ERROR Port-10259]: Port 10259 is in use

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

Создаю новый ubuntu или ubuntu server, без разницы, устанавливаю kubernetes
Дальше пытаюсь инициализировать с командой

```
sudo kubeadm init
```

и выводится такое сообшение

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.26.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks

error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR Port-10259]: Port 10259 is in use
    [ERROR Port-10257]: Port 10257 is in use
    [ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
```

не понимаю что делаю не так
попробывал перепазустить линукс, докер, кубернетис

ничего не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

порты заняты, не шарю в линуксе, не понимаю кем

Comment: посмотрите sudo netstat -ltup - должно написать, чем используются

Comment: Проверить каким процессом занят порт можно командой `lsof -i:10259`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :<port>
```

команда покажет чем порт занят

в моем случае было что то связанное с microk8s

команда

```
sudo snap remove microk8s
```

освободила порт